# Is my thermometer faulty?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

Today I decided to check my thermometer and measured the temperature of boiling tap water. The thermometer showed 98.5°C. The atmospheric pressure now is 742 mmHg.
According to the Clausius–Clapeyron equation, at this pressure the water should boil at 99.3°C.
Is my thermometer faulty or there are some other factors that could have affected the boiling temperature?

Thank you.

=====================================

UPDATE: Measuring ice in water gave me + 0.6°C degrees. Still not enough information to conclude how accurate (faulty) the thermometer is. You guys are probably right: the only way to tell is to use distilled water. Unless somebody measures tap water with a thermometer that is known to be accurate.

Comment: Tap water contains impurities and hence boils at a lower temperature than that calculated for pure water at a given pressure.

Comment: Measuring the temperature of ice water (should be 0°C) would probably be a more reliable means of calibration. Also, what type of thermometer is it? An error of about 1% is entirely reasonable for most types.

Comment: @user47033 Is it your guess or your experience? Because I know that some salts, when dissolved in water, increase the boiling temperature, rather than decrease it. Also, they say that even for the pure water the temperature of boiling water should be slightly above the calculated boiling temperature.

Comment: @lemon That is the next thing I was going to do. I am still freezing the water. The thermometer is laboratory-type mercury-in-glass thermometer. I have no idea how exactly accurate it is supposed to be. Hence the question. I thought it was supposed to be pretty accurate.

Comment: Precise temperature measurement is actually pretty hard. If you are within a couple of degrees, it's OK for most types of thermometers. You would have to buy a precision lab thermometer with calibration certificate to be guaranteed to be much better than that.

Comment: @CuriousOne You could be right. I got my thermometer a long time ago and until today I never wondered how precise it is. The label on it says that it is a laboratory thermometer. My guess was that it had to be pretty accurate. I wonder if anybody here have ever tried to actually measure the temperature of boiling tap water?

Comment: @user47033 , dissolved impurities would increase the boiling temperature.

Comment: @David White, I am not so sure about all the impurities. What about gases? They add chlorine in our tap water.

Comment: You can, of course, calibrate your thermometer yourself. Get yourself some distilled water and set up a freezing point and a boiling point measurement. Assuming that the thermometer is still linear (that's unlikely to change, I would say), you can then use a table or linear calibration formula to convert the readings into calibrated temperature values.

Comment: By the way, what makes you think the bulk of the tap water is actually boiling temperature? Rather than a degree or two below?

Comment: @CuriousOne, sounds like a big project to me :-) Though, I hope that I will be able to check the ice water in an hour or so.

Comment: @lemon, It was my guess. I immersed the thermometer into the boiling water. How else would one measure the temperature of a boiling liquid?

Comment: Very closely related, possibly duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94538/ice-bath-is-always-3c-why

Comment: @Chris White, Yet no conclusion was reached there either. I have a digital thermocouple, but I suspect it is less accurate than the thermometer that I currently use.

Comment: @GreenBear What I mean is that the water may not be heated to the right temperature in the first place. And even if it is, it may have cooled slightly by the time you measure it.

Comment: @lemon, No, I understood your point, and I suppose it might be valid. I just do not see a straightforward way to make sure that this is not the case.

Comment: @GreenBear , gas solubility in water is inversely related to temperature.  At higher temperatures, less gas dissolves in water.  This means that the dissolved gases will leave the water before it reaches its boiling point.

Comment: @David White, This is not apparent, but it makes sense, which kind of ruins my hopes that the thermometer might still be Ok.

Comment: @GreenBear , every measurement device has an associated precision.  As a rule, the less expensive the device, the less precise it is.  Your thermometer appears to be "off" by less than 1 deg C.  Assuming that you are dealing with a standard alcohol thermometer, that degree of precision seems very good to me.  Do you need a high degree of precision for your measurement?  If so, why?  Are you willing to spend quite a bit of money to get more precision?

Answer (score 2):

Tap water has various impurites , which lowers the vapor pressure of the resulting mixture. This leads to a lower boiling temperature.

Comment: If the impurities lower the vapour pressure then a higher temperature (to raise the vapour pressure to atmospheric) is needed to boil the water.

Comment: Should not the lowering of vapor pressure result in a higher boiling temperature?

Comment: Sugar syrup boils at notably higher temperatures than pure water.